# Ubuntu 22.04 power button settings

Tags: shutdown, 22.04

After installing Ubuntu 22.04, I wanted to shut down the computer immediately when pressing the top right-hand button (rather than making 4 selections). On earlier versions of Ubuntu I think this was possible through shutdown options in System settings/Desktop settings/Startup and Shutdown/Desktop Session. However, this option doesn’t seem to be obvious in Jammy Jellyfish.

Is there a way to do it? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are going to install Gnome Extensions via Firefox that won't work, Firefox is now a snap package and works in sandbox mode. Use *gnome-shell-extension-manager* instead of it

Answer (score 5):

The [Bring Out Submenu Of Power Off/Logout Button](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2917/bring-out-submenu-of-power-offlogout-button/) GNOME Shell extension is probably what you're looking for.

You may also want to see this thread for how to install GNOME Shell extensions: [How do I install and manage GNOME Shell extensions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-do-i-install-and-manage-gnome-shell-extensions?noredirect=1&lq=1)